# Alterar o nome do arquivo ao fazer upload

Tags: php

Como faço para alterar o nome do arquivo no momento do upload?

Só gostaria de adicionar na frete do nome do arquivo o `date('dmY')`.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
        $path = "./uploads/arquivos/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['arquivo']['name']);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            echo "Enviado";
        } else{
            echo "Erro";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

você vai ter que explodir(`explode()`) o nome do arquivo e com o array resultante juntar a data, segue o exemplo:

```
$nomeETipo = explode('.',$file['name']);
        $fileName = $nomeETipo[0].date('dmY') . "." . $nomeETipo[1];
```

onde o $nomeETipo[0] é o nome do arquivo e o $nomeETipo[1] é a extensão do arquivo.